# Issues with Marionette.Upgrade on Windows 7 when upgrading from Marionette 1 to 2

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to use https://github.com/marionettejs/Marionette.Upgrade on Windows 7 to upgrade a Marionette app I built in 1.6.2 to 2.

I've installed Python 2.7 and changed upgrade.py from `codemod = "%s/bin/codemod.py" % path.dirname(file)` to `codemod = "C:\Python27\python.exe"` based on other issues people have had with Upgrade on Windows.

However, I'm getting some errors I can't fix (I haven't used python before) and there are no changes when I ask for the replacement.

The command I use is `python C:\web\Marionette.Upgrade\upgrade.py C:\web\tl-git\app\webroot\js\apps\client\lists` and the errors I get look like

```
')close\' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. C:\Python27\python.exe: No module named --extensions
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

The following image shows the error and also the python info on my Windows installation:

[image: Python Info]

Comment: There are some issues running the script on Windows... check here: https://github.com/marionettejs/Marionette.Upgrade/issues/22